# how pass array to where clause in laravel eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel

Let's say i have this array of ids `[3,4,5]` which i get it from this Eloquent...

```
$route = Route::where('station_id',$stations_id)
                ->pluck('id')->toArray();
```

So, i wanted to use this array in where clause to get each schedule from each route and i did like this:

```
$schedule = Schedule::select('id')
                ->where('route_id',$route)
                ->get();
```

the problem is this showing the schedule ids of a one route only.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`whereIn`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#where-clauses):

```
$schedule = Schedule::select('id')
            ->whereIn('route_id', $route)
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have an array where you want to fetch all those IDs, you can use `whereIn()`,

```php
$schedule = Schedule::select('id')
                ->whereIn('route_id', $route)
                ->get();
```

Though, that said - you could define a relation between the station routes and schedules by useing relations in Eloquent - this would make it rather easier to get all relational data, see the link below.

- [Laravel docs for `whereIn()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#where-clauses)
- [Eloquent relational documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships)

Answer (score 2):

use whereIn

```
$schedule = Schedule::whereIn('route_id',$route)
                ->pluck('id');
```

Answer (score 2):

`->whereIn` in place of `->where`

```
$schedule = Schedule::select('id')
        ->whereIn('route_id', $route)
        ->get();
```